# activate ccTouchesBegan with a button in cocos2d and make it work just one time

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make something happen with ccTouchesBegan but i want to restrict that action to a button, meaning that the action by the button should trigger ccTouchesBegan but only one time. After the code inside ccTouchesBegan has finished, the interface should go back to normal and wait for the button to be pressed to trigger the action again.

I have made the button trigger ccTouchesBegan when its pressed but the problem is that once the button is pressed, the code inside ccTouchesBegan keeps working and doing the same thing from then on when a touch action on the simulator is done.

This is the code that i have so far.

this is a flag method that i have created so that i know the button has been pressed and i can control the actions on ccTouchesBegan.

```
- (void) selector{
    click = true;
  }
```

this is the button which calls the method selector.

```
- (void) button{
CCMenuItemImage *touchesMovedButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"ActionButton-Normal.png" 
                                                         selectedImage:@"ActionButton-Selected.png"
                                                                target:self 
                                                              selector:@selector(selector)
                                                              ];      

        CCMenu *selectorButton = [CCMenu menuWithItems: touchesMovedButton, nil];

        selectorButton.position = ccp(64, 64);

        [self addChild: selectorButton];
}
```

and this is the method ccTouchesBegan

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

//this part doesn't let the interface start the ccTouchesBegan code until the button has been pressed.
if (click == false) {
            return;       
        }
        // the else code starts when the button has been pressed.
        else{
            CCLOG(@"you have touched the interface!!");
        }
}
```

That's the code, the interface doesn't do any action until the button is pressed but after it's pressed it keeps printing the CCLOG each time i touch the interface. i just want it to do it once and then when i press the button again it should do it just one time again.

does anyone know how to do this? or maybe point out my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have the logical mistake. Use the Code below in the ccTouchesBegan It would work perfectly as you need...

```
if (click == false) 
{
    return;       
}
// the else code starts when the button has been pressed.
else if(click == true)
{
    CCLOG(@"you have touched the interface!!");
    click=false; // You need to make false if you want to make touch single time enabled
}
```